# OpenAPI & Python: How to use apiKey security scheme?

Tags: python, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to use an API with an OpenAPI specification via Python. I generated the openapi_client and used one of the generated examples to get started. The first call to the API succeeds, but subsequent calls fail due to an invalid session ID.

```
  securitySchemes:
    user_session_authentication:
      description: [...]
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: SOME_PREFIX_user_session_id
security:
  - user_session_authentication: [] # default for all actions is user_session_id!
```

```
import openapi_client
from openapi_client.api import some_api
from openapi_client.model.inline_response200 import InlineResponse200
from openapi_client.model.inline_response2002 import InlineResponse2002
from pprint import pprint

with openapi_client.ApiClient() as api_client:
    username = "john"
    password = "45d75ii47"
    
    api_instance = some_api.SomeApi(api_client)
    username = username
    password = password
    body = function_a("foo")

    api_response = api_instance.foo(username=username, password=password, body=body)
    pprint(api_response)
    
    api_response = api_instance.bar()
    pprint(api_response)
```

The http response to foo() contains the key-value pair `'user_session_id': '1bf92fc3-7f2a-450f-a472-03a07a70bd8d'`. How do I add this key-value pair to the header of the second request? Currently, the header of the second request contains just the following: `{'Accept': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'OpenAPI-Generator/1.0.0/python'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291995/the-specifics-of-adding-a-header-to-an-api-call-with-a-swagger-codegen-client-in) question and adapted the code for my use case:

```
import openapi_client
from openapi_client.api import some_api
from openapi_client import Configuration
from openapi_client.model.inline_response200 import InlineResponse200
from openapi_client.model.inline_response2002 import InlineResponse2002
from pprint import pprint

with openapi_client.ApiClient() as api_client:
    username = "john"
    password = "45d75ii47"
    
    api_instance = some_api.SomeApi(api_client)
    username = username
    password = password
    body = function_a("foo")

    api_response = api_instance.foo(username=username, password=password, body=body)
    pprint(api_response)
    
    conf = Configuration()
    conf.api_key = {"SOME_PREFIX_user_session_id": api_response.user_session_id}
    api_client = openapi_client.ApiClient(None, "SOME_PREFIX_user_session_id", conf.get_api_key_with_prefix("user_session_id"))
    api_instance = some_api.SomeApi(api_client)

    api_response = api_instance.bar()
    pprint(api_response)
```